# Where's the Debug button in Excel VBA error

Tags: excel, vba

Simple question I haven't been able to find the answer to with Google:

How do I get the "Debug" button to appear in the pop-up that appears when there's a run-time error in Excel 2010 VBA?  I've seen it in the past, but now its missing.

Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: The ability to debug from the VBIDE has not changed with Office 2010. If there is a locked project this button will be disabled or for some errors you simply cannot debug the error and in that case it will not show. What is the exact error and what do you get?  Is it just the option to 'End'?

Answer (score 3):

In VB Editor, Go Tools \ Options. General Tab, Error Trapping section, Then switch to Break on all Errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `On Error Goto xxx` error handling in your VBA then you won't see the Debug/Halt dialog - this is by design, because you are expected to provide your own handling routines.

This also applies if you are using `On Error Resume Next`, except that the error is completely ignored.

If you use the setting `On Error Goto 0`, (the default setting, equivalent to not specifying either of the above settings) then you will see the Dialog box when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to debug your code, you can do that from "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications", you can use Alt + F11 shortcut to open it from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the debugging mode in the settings, that often helps. In addition, I've read reports that say that the Debug button can disappear if the VBA code is in a hosted object, so moving it to a standard module may help.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes if you run your method directly from *Immediate* window.

VBA editor, in order to display Debug option needs to break the code on some line and it is impossible when error occurs on the line in *Immediate* window.

---

Example:

If you run the code below directly in *Immediate* window:

```
MsgBox 1 / 0
```

editor will display the following window:

[image: error directly in Immediate window]

However if you wrap this line of code into method:

```
Sub test
    MsgBox 1 / 0
End Sub
```

and call it from *Immediate* window like that:

```
Call test
```

editor will raise an error because of the same operation but run-time error window will look like that:

[image: with wrapping method]