# Subscript out of range error without debug option

Tags: excel, vba

I get this error:

> subscript out of range.

I do not have the debug option, only OK and HELP.

One time on 20 the macro works. The rest of time I'm getting this error.

The code makes you choose the path you want to search and next the text you want to find in the workbook in the path chosen. It searches in sub folders too. After that it sends back the file name, sheet name, which cell and what text is in the cell.

The macro runs but pops that error after searching 4 to 5 different files.

```
Dim AppObject As New Class1
Public WS As Worksheet
Sub SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Optional Folderpath As Variant, Optional Str As Variant)
Dim myfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Single
Dim Folders() As String
Dim Folder As Variant
ReDim Folders(0)
Dim wbk As Workbook

If IsMissing(Folderpath) Then
    Set WS = Sheets.Add

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Nom de la Personne:", Title:="Personne a chercher", Type:=2)

    If Str = "" Then Exit Sub

    WS.Range("A1") = "Semaine"
    WS.Range("B1") = "Journée"
    WS.Range("C1") = "Cellule"
    WS.Range("D1") = "Nom"

    Folderpath = myfolder

    Value = Dir(myfolder, &H1F)
Else
    If Right(Folderpath, 2) = "\\" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Value = Dir(Folderpath, &H1F)
End If

Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If GetAttr(Folderpath & Value) = 16 Then
            Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
            ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)

        ElseIf Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folderpath & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    'Expand all groups in sheet
                    sht.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8
                    Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        Do
                            Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            WS.Range("A1").Offset(Lrow, 0).Value = Value
                            WS.Range("B1").Offset(Lrow, 0).Value = sht.Name
                            WS.Range("C1").Offset(Lrow, 0).Value = c.Address
                            WS.Range("D1").Offset(Lrow, 0).Value = c.Value
                            Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(c)
                        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                    End If
                Next sht
            End If
            Workbooks(Value).Close False
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
For Each Folder In Folders
    SearchWKBooksSubFolders (Folderpath & Folder & "\")
Next Folder
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619) and the guide on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *Where* does the error occur?

Comment: `Option Explicit` and why use `&H1F` instead of something more descriptive or a vba constant?

Comment: Comment out your error handlers or make them more selective, and you might find you're getting errors you didn't expect.  you should also consider breaking this up into separate methods - eg create a function to return a list/collection of matching files, given a starting folder.  Your locig will then be easier to follow/debug.

Comment: Comment out your error handlers or make them more selective, and you might find you're getting errors you didn't expect. You might also consider breaking this up into separate methods - eg create a function to return a list/collection of matching files, given a starting folder. Your logic will then be easier to follow/debug.

Comment: See [Where's the debug button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407061/wheres-the-debug-button-in-excel-vba-error)

Answer (score -1):

you can debug on your own without the debugger of the IDE.
Simply put `On Error Resume Next`/`On Error Goto 0` very close to each other in order to restrict the statements which can raise errors. ie the second `On Error Goto 0` is too far.

I can debug more effectively simply putting between statements something like that:

```
a = a + 1
debug.print "I am here"
b = b -5
debug.print "I am there"
c = 5 / 0
debug.print "You can't see me"
```

So you can find when the error is raised